# Get Object to Fly From the Left Side to the Right Side of the Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Starting with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JonChambers/dp7ajcvz/3/) we see a basic animation of a box flying from its start position to its finish position. This is the known good code. (I tried it as a stackoverflow snippet, but it didn't work here for some reason.)

HTML

```
<div id="start">Start</div>
<div id="finish">Finish</div>
<div id="fly">Fly</div>
```

CSS

```
#start{
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  left:0px;
}
#finish{
  position:absolute;
  background:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  left:200px;
}
#fly{
  position:absolute;
  background:yellow;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  left:0px;
  transition:1000ms;
}
#fly.finish{
  left:200px
  }
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("fly").className = "finish";
```

-

Unlike the fiddle above [this fiddle below](https://jsfiddle.net/JonChambers/0yv8gbtu/3/) however does not work. Rather than transitioning gently from the start location to the finish, it starts at the finish. This is because it should transition from a "left" property to a "right" property.

HTML

```
<div id="start">Start</div>
<div id="finish">Finish</div>
<div id="fly">Fly</div>
```

CSS

```
#start{
  position:absolute;
  background:red;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  left:0px;
}
#finish{
  position:absolute;
  background:blue;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  right:0px;
}
#fly{
  position:absolute;
  background:yellow;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  line-height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  left:0px;
  right:auto;
  transition:1000ms;
}
#fly.finish{
  right:0px;
  left:auto;
  }
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("fly").className = "finish";
```

Although I understand why this doesn't work, I need a box to fly to the right of the screen from just off the left edge of the screen. Most solutions to this issue either look strange on extremely wide screen devices, or have a slow response time on narrow mobile devices. I want an animation that's responsive to browser width, travelling more slowly across narrow screens and more quickly across wide screens.

What is the most elegant solution for this?

Ideally I'd like not to use any external libraries, but if I must, the page is already using jquery, so that would be the ideal one to use if that helps.

I'm not opposed to writing extremely long JavaScript functions, but shorter is always better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know that the animation doesn't work cause can't animate two different attributes, in this case, changing left and right value in hope for the element to be animated.

My suggestion would be this:

```
#fly.finish {
  left:calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

this is assuming that the box is always 100px width. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Change your flying elements "left" property to (100% - elements width) as shown below.

```
#fly.finish{
  left: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: Love your answer, but you were beaten to it.